# Use Mockito to make a partial mock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

You've got a class that you need to override the behavior of one of it's methods.  How to partially mock "size" with Mockito?

```
class NaughtyLinkedList extends LinkedList {
    public int size() { throw new RuntimeException("don't call me");}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: You can do proper partial mocks since Mockito 1.8.
Note: The lines that are commented out *don't work* since the "when" API *executes it's argument once*
Note: All calls that aren't explicitly stubbed call the real object's methods.

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

...
@Test
public void partialMockWithMock(){
    List mock = Mockito.mock(NaughtyLinkedList.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    mock.add(new Object()); // this calls the real function

    //Mockito.when(mock.size()).thenReturn(2); // This lines throws the RuntimeException because it actually executes it's argument.

    Mockito.doReturn(2).when(mock).size();
    assertEquals(2,mock.size());
}

@Test
public void partialMockWithSpy() {
    List list = new NaughtyLinkedList();
    List spy = Mockito.spy(list);

    // optionally, you can stub out some methods:
    //Mockito.when(spy.size()).thenReturn(2); //Can't use "when" API, as it will execute it's argument once.
    Mockito.doReturn(2).when(spy).size();

    assertEquals(2,spy.size());
}
```

See [Mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) for background.